# How implement Push Notifications firebase xamarin.ios c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing an application that works on the iPhone through the xamarin.ios with firebase backend. I want **Push Notifications FCM Firebase**, but I couldn't, I want that code in AppDelegate.cs

Comment: Hi mahmudamen.
Your question would be better with the following things in mind:

- don't repeat your question in the description
- tell what you have done already
- provide code if you have some.
- add apropreate tags as you have done with xamarin. Mybe add Firebase FCM too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To implement Push Notifications firebase with xamarin.ios in C#, you can have a try with [Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging/).

And there are detailed steps about [setting-up-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-client-app-on-ios](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md#setting-up-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-client-app-on-ios) there.

Code example in `AppDelegate` and `Sample project` are also available.

Additional, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started#register-your-app-for-push-notifications) is document about creating push notification certificates and settings in iOS app.