# How to make video call with IceLink, when the peer app is closed

Tags: xamarin.forms, icelink

I have a Xamarin.Forms app. In it, I implemented video chat functionality (that supports iOS and Android) using IceLink. The video chat works when both the caller and the recipient have their apps open. Now I wonder how I can make a call to a device which has the app not open.

Comment: You can send notification by Firebase Cloud Messaging when device do not open, click the notification to open your application, show the video chat page.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thank you for your answer. Actually, not sure this will do. We would need the app to behave like e.g. skype or whatsApp etc. So that I could buzz a peer while his app is off (or running always at the background), informing him to accept the call.

Comment: If you use  a high priority FCM for an app, it will allow that app to run services in the background for a short period of time. This would be a good alternative to having a background service that polls an app in the background.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/#background-execution-limits-in-android-80

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Would it work for iOS also? Couldn't you please refer me to some example implementation? Thanks.

Comment: For iOS achievement, you can refer to this thread :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984019/how-implement-push-notifications-firebase-xamarin-ios-c-sharp

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thank you! If you make it your answer, I will mark it.

Comment: I moved comment to answer. Thanks for your update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Android**

You can send notification by Firebase Cloud Messaging when device do not open, click the notification to open your application, show the video chat page.

If you use a high priority FCM for an app, it will allow that app to run services in the background for a short period of time. This would be a good alternative to having a background service that polls an app in the background:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/#background-execution-limits-in-android-80

**For iOS**

You can refer to Jack's reply.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60001529/10627299