# Getting no Firebase Cloud Messaging Token in Xamarin iOS when started from Windows PC on an iPhone test device. [Updated]

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

### Summary

I try to use the Firebase Cloud Messaging to send Notification to a xamarin app for Android and iOS. Android already works.

I followed mainly the guide in this answer (and several others):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60001529/8542816

I get this error message:

`An error occurred: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. Callstack: '  at Productname.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0008c] in C:\Path\repos\Productname\Productname.iOS\AppDelegate.cs:56`

Setting:

- I develope on a Windows PC and debug on a physical IPhone with iOS 14.4.2
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging 4.7.1
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core 6.10.4
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Installations 1.7.0
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID 4.8.0

### What I've tried

While debugging i realized that `Messaging.SharedInstance` is null. When i searched for it i came across 2 possible solutions:

1. Downgrading to an older FCM Framework (I tried Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging 3.1.2 and corresponding downgrades of other Framework dependincies)
2. Problems with `GoogleService-Info.plist` (Triple checked the values, redownloaded)

### Code Snippets

GoogleService-Info.plist (is set as BundleResource):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>123456789012-replaced123456789012345678901234.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <key>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.123456789012-replaced123456789012345678901234</string>
    <key>API_KEY</key>
    <string>HereIsThe_KeyWhichIReplaced123456789012</string>
    <key>GCM_SENDER_ID</key>
    <string>123456789012</string>
    <key>PLIST_VERSION</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>BUNDLE_ID</key>
    <string>de.companyname.productname</string>
    <key>PROJECT_ID</key>
    <string>productname-a43fc</string>
    <key>STORAGE_BUCKET</key>
    <string>productname-a43fc.appspot.com</string>
    <key>IS_ADS_ENABLED</key>
    <false></false>
    <key>IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED</key>
    <false></false>
    <key>IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>IS_GCM_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>GOOGLE_APP_ID</key>
    <string>1:123456789012:ios:0123456789abcdef012345</string>
    <key>DATABASE_URL</key>
    <string>https://productname-a43fc.firebaseio.com</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

AppDelegate.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Firebase.InstanceID;
using Firebase.Core;
using Firebase.CloudMessaging;
using Foundation;
using Productname.Models.Global;
using UIKit;
using UserNotifications;

namespace Productname.iOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IMessagingDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            // Register your app for remote notifications.
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = (IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate)this;

                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                    Console.WriteLine(granted);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                // iOS 9 or before
                var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            }


            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

            Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this; // <-- The Execution crashes here

            InstanceId.SharedInstance.GetInstanceId(InstanceIdResultHandler);

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

        [Export("messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:")]
        public void DidReceiveRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken)
        {
            //Never Fired
            FirebaseToken.Singleton.Token = fcmToken;
            Console.WriteLine($"Firebase registration token: {fcmToken}");
            LogInformation(nameof(DidReceiveRegistrationToken), $"Firebase registration token: {fcmToken}");
        }


        void InstanceIdResultHandler(InstanceIdResult result, NSError error)
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                LogInformation(nameof(InstanceIdResultHandler), $"Error: {error.LocalizedDescription}");
                return;
            }

            LogInformation(nameof(InstanceIdResultHandler), $"Remote Instance Id token: {result.Token}");
        }

        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            HandleMessage(userInfo);

            // Print full message.
            LogInformation(nameof(DidReceiveRemoteNotification), userInfo);

            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
        }

        [Export("messaging:didReceiveMessage:")]
        public void DidReceiveMessage(Messaging messaging, RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
        {
            // Handle Data messages for iOS 10 and above.
            HandleMessage(remoteMessage.AppData);

            LogInformation(nameof(DidReceiveMessage), remoteMessage.AppData);
        }

        void HandleMessage(NSDictionary message)
        {
        }

        public static void ShowMessage(string title, string message, UIViewController fromViewController, Action actionForOk = null)
        {
            var alert = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Ok", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (obj) => actionForOk?.Invoke()));
            fromViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
        }

        void LogInformation(string methodName, object information) => Console.WriteLine($"\nMethod name: {methodName}\nInformation: {information}");
    }
}
```

Remote Notification in Info.plist is activated.

When i comment out the line `Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;` the app will start and work perfectly besides missing notification functionality.

Any hints or further debug approaches much appreciated.

### Update

I managed to get my hands on a MacBook. I started the App from the MacBook via Visual Studio on the very same testing iPhone Device and it worked instantly. I would like to keep the developing and testing process on my windows PC though. Is it even possible?

Comment: Do you have tried clear the cache? you can refer to this page for some infos:https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/181967/xamarin-firebase-ios-cloudmessaging-messaging-sharedinstance-is-null

Comment: @Steven I actually followed this guide for downgrading but overlooked the part about clearing the XamarinBuildDownloadCache folder and i only deleted the bin and obj folders. Unfortunatly this didnt change the outcome. I tried clearing it and building with up to date Firebase Libraries and clearing it + downgraded to Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging 3.1.2)