# xamarin android Event on notification received

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin

I am looking for a event for on notification receive event it looks like this exists in firebase but I can't find a implementation for Xamarin

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Does this just not exist ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows#implement-firebasemessagingservice

Comment: Sweet exactly what I wanted can you put that as a answer ? Is is possible to do the same on IOS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows#implement-firebasemessagingservice)

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is is possible to do the same on IOS ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984019/how-implement-push-notifications-firebase-xamarin-ios-c-sharp